# Gitlab CI variables for merge request source branch, source

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

so in my gitlab ci, i'm trying to find a way to get the source of the merge request source branch.

I'll exaplin:

i create a branch from main > my_branch

i create a branch from my_branch > add_stuff

What i try to do is:

if i create a Merge Request from add_stuff AND
if the merge request_target branch is not my_branch (so the source of the branch add_stuff)

my pipeline failed

i have the CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME to get the target of the merge request

CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME to get the merge request source (so in this case add_feature)

but i would like something like CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME who, in this case, will be my_branch

this is to avoid code merged by mistake in the main branch who is supposed to represent the latest release

thank you

Answer (score 0):

So based on chat gpt answer i could do something like

```
get_source_branch:
  script:
    - export TOKEN=<your GitLab API token>
    - export PROJECT_ID=<your project ID>
    - export MR_IID=$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID
    - export SOURCE_BRANCH=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/merge_requests/$MR_IID" | jq -r '.source_branch')
    - export SOURCE_OF_SOURCE_BRANCH=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/merge_requests?source_branch=$SOURCE_BRANCH" | jq -r '.[].source_branch')
    - echo "Source branch of source branch: $SOURCE_OF_SOURCE_BRANCH"
```

i'll test it and give feedback

EDIT: this didn't work, it just return the merge_request source branch